# IronPython windows registry get installation paths

Tags: c#, windows, ironpython, registry

I'm trying to get what software's installed on my computer as well as the path they're installed to.

I found a link which provided code to get installed software, but I'm unsure how to get the installation paths, and how to associate a certain path(s) with a particular software package.

```
# prints out the names of installed software
# just need to find the installtion paths
from Microsoft.Win32 import Registry
products = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("Installer\\Products")
for product_name in products.GetSubKeyNames():
    product_key = products.OpenSubKey(product_name)
    print product_key.GetValue("ProductName")
```

As a side note, is there a tutorial/guide somewhere which details how to use the Windows Registry (such as the keys used above)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with regedit for a while, I found that installation paths are located at `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Folders`

```
from Microsoft.Win32 import Registry
paths = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Installer\\Folders").GetValueNames()
for ipy_path in paths:
    print ipy_path
```

It doesn't tell me which path is associated with which program, but I can figure that out now that I have the paths.